# IIS connection to active directory for GroupPrincipal user.IsMemberOf

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, groupprincipal

I have tested this in Visual Studio 2013 and it works fine, but after publishing to the web server, I get a 401 error. Here is the code, but I don't think its the issue. I think its the set up on the IIS server that I inherited, since it worked in Visual Studio using my user account. Users are able to login using active directory accounts and passwords on the published site, but when I try to add or remove the user programmatically in the AD group FIDO_Users is when I get the error. The update button is in a Telerik RadGrid FormTemplate, but I am just doing a OnClick from the RadButton to run the code below for AD Group updates. I have tried adding the IUSR to Active Directory since I am using Anonymous and Forms Authentication, but get the same result. What else am I missing?

```
protected void btnUpdate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ducks.org");

        Button btn = sender as Button;
        RadTextBox rtxtb = btn.Parent.FindControl("UNameIDBox") as RadTextBox;
        string txtb = rtxtb.Text;

        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, txtb);
        GroupPrincipal groupadAdmin = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "FIDO_Users");

        RadButton rbFind = btn.Parent.FindControl("rbOpen") as RadButton;
        bool rbChekced = rbFind.Checked;

        if (rbChekced)
        {
            if (!user.IsMemberOf(groupadAdmin))
            {
                groupadAdmin.Members.Add(user);
                groupadAdmin.Save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            groupadAdmin.Members.Remove(user);
            groupadAdmin.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: IUSR is a local account. You're going to have to pass credentials with the required AD permissions to your PrincipalContext() constructor. Either that or run this application in an app pool that runs as a user with the required AD permissions. I prefer the former method.

Comment: Yes, adding a user login and password of the admins to the PrincipalContext worked, but I also had to update Active Directory since it is a special group. The admins of the web app had to be on the OU with special permissions for it to work.